# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar las rutas de login de Laravel 5.4 a 10.20.0?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

Tengo un proyecto de Laravel que fué desarrollado con la versión 5.4 o 5.5 de Laravel, he optado por migrarlo a la última versión de Laravel (10.20.0), para ello, he creado un proyecto nuevo y he empezado a copiar y pegar los seeders, migraciones, controladores y rutas.

Tengo problemas con las siguientes rutas, dentro del fichero `web.php`:

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
$this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
$this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Error que recibo:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar::get()
```

En su momento, cuando creé el sistema de login, lo hice automáticamente con Laravel